Change of measure with respect to which to integrate
I was wondering why the following equality.
Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ a measurable space, $\mu:\mathcal{M}\to [0,+\infty]$ a positive measure and consider $f:X\to [0,+\infty]$ a measurable function. Then, we can define:
$$\varphi:\mathcal{M}\to [0,+\infty], \quad \varphi(E)=\int_E f\ d\mu, \hspace{4pt} \forall E\in \mathcal{M}$$
It can be shown that $\varphi$ is a positive measure.
Moreover, it is true that $\forall g:X\to [0,+\infty]$ measurable function, then $$\int_X g \ d\varphi=\int_X gf \ d\mu$$
Is this true by definition $($ since, roughly speaking, $d\varphi$ is "the derivative of $\int_E f \ d\mu$"$)$ or is there another way of looking at this "substitution" between measures?

Verify it for simple functions and take limits. This question has been asked many times on this site.

this is a theorem. First for indicator function $g=\chi_E$, it is by definition. Then, consider non-negative linear combinations, then apply monotone convergence to deduce it for all $g$. And it is this theorem which justifies the notation $\frac{d\phi}{d\mu}=f$ for the Radon-Nikodym derivative (because we just love it when things behave like fractions).
